# WebBrowser control chops off lower 25% of screen

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

This is all there is to my code. I've tried moving the `WindowState` assignment to the `Form1_Load` procedure, but that doesn't make any difference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://empire.goodgamestudios.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get the WebBrowser control to display the entire page. Do you want a web browser that only shows you the top 75% of the screen? The question was in the TITLE...

Comment: The details you provided are too specific...try attaching an image as per your problem, so we would be able to circumvent that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out!

**The problem is**:

Your `WebBrowser` Control is using **IE 7**(*by default*) to render the pages, the pages you navigate to.

**Solution**:

You need the `WebBrowser` Control to render the pages using the latest version of Internet Explorer *(i.e; the latest version installed on your machine..mine one is **IE 11**)* and the problem will be resolved.

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(VS.85).aspx#browser_emulation), the Value - **11001** *(0x2AF9)* says:

> Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode,
>   regardless of the [declared !DOCTYPE directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242(v=vs.85).aspx). Failing to [declare a
>   !DOCTYPE directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242(v=vs.85).aspx) causes the page to load in Quirks.

---

#### **Steps**:

**↪** You need to set the `(DWORD)` to your application with the value **11001**.

For this, navigate to to the registry directory as shown below:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                     WebBrowser_Test.vshost.exe = (DWORD) 11001
```

**↪** Create a new **Key** and name it as **`WebBrowser_Test.vshost.exe`** as shown in the picture below:

[image: app.exe]

***Note:*** *Change the prefix `WebBrowser_Test` as per the name of your application*.

**↪** Now, add the decimal value **11001** to the **Key** which you created.

*The image below will give a clear representation of what has been said above:*

### [image: DWORD]

**↪** Now, run your app and you should be able to see it that the `WebBrowser` Control isn't chopped off anymore.

[image: ain't chopped :)]