# Get .net webbrowser full screen event

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a windows form application,there is a webbrowser control on the middle of the form. that navigates to a Youtube video, the full screen button of the video doesn't work.

How can i get the fullscreen event (when triggered using html or flash)?

Comment: try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526955/webbrowser-control-chops-off-lower-25-of-screen/39538561#39538561)

Comment: The WebBrowser control [ignores the OnFullScreen event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768338(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @stuartd as it says it for when you open something. but i have an html butoon. am i wrong ?

Comment: @Rakitić i can make it fullscreen in code . but i don't know when the user will bush the html full screen button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still shocked by how bad IE 11 shows web pages. So I strongly recommend using another engine like Chromium. View this post in order to know about library options.

I went with [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) and there is a great [How To Guide in here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990346/Using-HTML-as-UI-Elements-in-a-WinForms-Applicatio) But the browser lakes just full screens to form boundaries, so be noted in case using this option you might need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e){
this.KeyDown+= new KeyEventHandler(MainForm_KeyDown);}
void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
if( e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
MessageBox.Show("What is the Ctrl?");}
```

Comment: Dear user3060520 i want to do it by html button inside the webbrowser. to a keyboard or .net button.